# Asus ZenPhone 5 Android Keyboard has no Hindi language input?

Tags: keyboard, languages

I bought an Asus Zenphone 5 (nice piece of phone for a cheap price btw). However, there is no Hindi keyboard input. Strange, given Hindi and other related languages using the same script count for about 300 million users (about as much as Arabic).

Anyway, how can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Try a different keyboard, SwiftKey, Google Keyboard etc and see what suits your needs.

Comment: Is the ASUS keyboard not the same as Android Keyboard? Doesn't android keyboard handle South Asian scripts by default?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. I don't have an Asus to hand. But since MOST manufacturers have their own Keyboards I would assume so. You could always try a few anyway. I don't like Google's one much myself, and use SwiftKey (which is now free)... It's worth a shot anyway. Check on the Play Store if you have Google Keyboard installed, if not then it's more than likely an Asus own one.